# Is backbonejs default sort alphabetically with added model to a collection?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/adamchenwei/966pob6c/

Script Here:

```
var people = new Backbone.Collection;

people.comparator = function(a, b) {
  return a.get('name') < b.get('name') ? -1 : 1;
};

var tom = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Tom'});
var rob = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Rob'});
var tim = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Tim'});

people.add(tom);
people.add(rob);
people.add(tim);

console.log(people.indexOf(rob) === 0); // true
console.log(people.indexOf(tim) === 1); // true
console.log(people.indexOf(tom) === 2); // true
```

I can not comprehend why when these three objects are not index according to its added order but alphabetical? Is there way to disable BB from doing so after a model is added to a collection?

Comment: You don't want Backbone to use the `comparator` that you've given it? BTW, your `comparator` is missing a case, two argument comparators are supposed to return -1, **0**, or 1. And your fiddle has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @muistooshort I did not know comparator is relevant actually... I got this from a tutorial http://weiadesigner/backbonejs/fundamentals/ So... comparator is the one did the sorting? I did not see anywhere it is been used!

Comment: @muistooshort in term of my question, I wonder why rob index is 0 while its added after tom? that's a example.

Comment: If you got that comparator function from a tutorial then you need to find a better tutorial as that comparator is incomplete.

Comment: @muistooshort would u wish to complete it for me? :) Because I have no idea how to complete it.....

Comment: Some searching for "backbone comparator" should help you.

Comment: k will do ia. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator):

> **comparator** `collection.comparator`
>
> By default there is no **comparator** for a collection. If you define a comparator, it will be used to maintain the collection in sorted order. This means that as models are added, they are inserted at the correct index in `collection.models`.

You've given your collection a `comparator`. Therefore your collection will always be sorted as specified by your `comparator`.

Also, your `comparator` is broken. A two-argument comparator should return -1, 0, or 1 just like the comparator function you use with the standard [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You could use either of these:

```
people.comparator = 'name';
people.comparator = function(m) { return m.get('name') }
```

to properly sort your collection by name.